# C++ Constructor member assignment optimization

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it's possible for C++ compilers to optimize in a case like this.  Assume we have a class like:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : a(10), b(11), c(12) {};
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
```

And I use this class like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Foo f;
  f.a = 50;
  f.b = 51;
  f.c = 52;
  return 0;
}
```

Would the compiler generate code to set `a`, `b`, and `c` to their respective default values of 10, 11, 12, and then set them to 50, 51, 52?  Or is it allowed to delay assigning those initial values and instead only ever assign the values later (50,51,52) since there is no read in between the writes?  Basically will it have to generate code to write those six values, or can it optimize to three?

If so, does this apply also to more complex types (structs, classes)?  What is it called and where can I read more about this?

If not, why not?

Comment: You can remove the constructor, provide default member initializers instead, and your class will become an aggregate. Then you can do aggregate initialization and not worry about it.

Comment: Unfortunately the class in question is not under my control -- Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: I would think that unless the compiler can check that every instantiation immediately discards the values that it would have to do the constructor as given.

Comment: As for you question, since the constructor,s definition is provided inline, I think it's likely modern compilers will do the optimization you want. It's perfectly valid under the as-if rule. No way to say for sure without looking an generated assembly, however.

Comment: I got curious and checked. Here's [GCC and Clang's output](https://godbolt.org/g/Wg4UfD). GCC optimizes aggressively from -O1, and Clang from -O2.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you so much!  That website is awesome - hadn't seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This obviously depends on the compiler--but there are certainly at least some compilers that can and will eliminate the dead stores. In fact, depending on how you use the results, the compiler may eliminate *all* stores, dead or otherwise.

For example, if we compile your code exactly as it is right now, we end up with assembly language like this:

```
xor eax, eax
ret
```

That's it--since you never use any of the values you store, it eliminates all the code dealing with those values entirely. All that's left is the fact that `main` returns `0`, so it just generates code for `main` to return zero.

That's probably not a case you care a whole lot about though, so let's expand the code a bit, to show something closer to what you probably care about.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : a(10), b(11), c(12) {};
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Foo const &f) {
      return os << "(" << f.a << ", " << f.b << ", " << f.c << ")";
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  f.a = 50;
  f.b = 51;
  f.c = 52;

  std::cout << f << "\n";
}
```

In this case, the compiler still eliminates all the storage involved, and produces code to just directly write out the values we gave as literals in the source:

```
mov esi, 50
mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
```

[and the same sequence repeated for 51 and 52].

Reference:

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/CRUFdz)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the compiler can optimize to remove the initialization. This technique is called [dead store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store) optimization. Determining whether a dead store occurs is part of [data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis).

Answer (score -2):

It will first assign the three values to a,b and c and then after that change them to the later assigned values.

This is because in c++, execution is line by line. So first the object gets declared and it gets values assigned by the constructor as soon as declared. After that a,b and c values are changed.

To *optimize* it, you can use the constructor with default arguments like this

```
class Foo{
public:
int a, b, c;
Foo(x = 10, y = 11, z = 12){
   a = x;
   b = y;
   c = z;
}
};

int main(){
Foo f; //a gets 10, b gets 11, c gets 12
Foo fi(51, 52, 53); //a gets 51, b gets 52, c gets 53
}
```

Comment: "This is because in c++, execution is line by line.". By this you really mean "The compiler can optimise as it pleases so long as the resulting output, given any input, is identical to what would happen if the C++ execution is line by line." In the OP's case, the optimiser could produce `int main(){}`.